# ffmpeg - Merge mp4 video with wav audio

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, youtube

I want to get the best audio for a youtube video upload. I found out that mov can retain the audio intact. I've tried doing so, but I get an AAC audio instead.

Here's the command I use:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mov
```

While the audio.wav properties are these:

```
Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
```

the output.mov audio properties are these:

```
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
```

Do I need to pass something else to the ffmpeg command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems this did the trick, someone more skilled in this area could verify it:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mov
```

Comment: Keep the `-c:a copy`.

Comment: What you're doing is unnecessarily decoding the audio and re-encoding it to PCM. This doesn't introduce any loss, but using `-c:a copy`, as Mulvya suggests, will speed up the command.

Comment: Makes no difference in the end, but you could change `-c:v copy -c:a copy` to `-c copy`. If you don't know the exact stream order of the inputs you could use `-map 0:v -map 1:a` instead.

Comment: Also, consider using `-c:a flac` instead and output to .mkv container. You'll still get lossless audio to feed to YouTube but it will be a smaller file size to upload.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I thought of using mkv, but YouTube doesn't list it as a suggested container format.

Comment: @panosl I've never had any problems using mkv to upload to YouTube.

Comment: ...recently at least. They got a lot better over the years.

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg \
  -i original.mp4 \
  -i new-audio.flac \
  -c:v copy \
  -map 0:v:0 \
  -c:a copy \
  -map 1:a:0 \
  video-with-new-flac-audio.mp4
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).